# Display a webpage in blackberry using BrowserField

Tags: blackberry, browser

I found this code, which I guess is for the java file, but does that actually display it, or how do I do the XML? And does Blackberry have a nice GUI for the BB UI yet?

```
import net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;

public class BrowserFieldDemo extends UiApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BrowserFieldDemo app = new BrowserFieldDemo();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public BrowserFieldDemo()
    {
        pushScreen(new BrowserFieldDemoScreen());
    }
}

class BrowserFieldDemoScreen extends MainScreen
{
    public BrowserFieldDemoScreen()
    {
        BrowserFieldConfig myBrowserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        myBrowserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(myBrowserFieldConfig);

        add(browserField);
        browserField.requestContent("http://www.blackberry.com");
    }
}
```

I got the code from [this page](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Browser_field_1184788_11.jsp)

My end-game is to have a web-based app using HTML5 since BB is a b*tch to program. I figure the HTML is super easy, and this way I just have to figure out how to show a webpage. Is there any reason I should not attempt this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 webapp is the best solution since not all BBs use the same code

Answer (score 1):

> I found this code, which I guess is for the java file...

Yes

> but does that actually display it?

Yes. Why not?

> ...or how do I do the xml?

Don't get it

> And does blackberry have a nice GUI for the BB UI yet?

No. I use BB plugin for Eclipse and it is not hard

> My end-game is to have a web-based app using HTML5

Good solution but depends on the app you are trying to develop

> ...since BB is a b*tch to program

Don't think so

> I figure the HTML is super easy, and this way I just have to figure
>   out how to show a webpage. Is there any reason I should not attempt
>   this method?

It's good if you want to develop for multiple platforms but you are not going to be able to create an app that is as powerfull as a native one